# Local performance counters show up when adding remote counters in PerfMon

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, perfmon, performance-counters

I'm trying to get performance counters of machine A (server running Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit) in PerfMon. PerfMon is running on machine B (another server used as a desktop). The goal of this is to run load tests against web sites served by machine A and get performance information.

Both machines are in the same domain and as far as I'm aware, I have the necessary privileges to get remote counters. The domain is not under my control - I'm working on-site at a client. They don't do load tests so they don't know how to help.

When I try to add the counters (IIS, ASP.NET & CPU counters), they seem to be added to PerfMon but the data that shows up in PerfMon seems to be coming from the local machine (machine B), not from machine A. I tried to run ~20 tests and the strange this is that in one test, the correct counters showed up. In all other cases I got local values.

I'm not an admin but a developer so I don't have enough experience to figure out what this is - I'm familiar with performance counters but I've never encountered this situation. Is there anything that I may be doing wrong that causes this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Remote Registry service is running on the remote host.